# How can I refine a REST query based on a linked module?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm trying to get all accounts that do not have an associated document.

This is what I have in mind:

```
$parameters = array(
            'session' => $this->getSessionId(),
            'module_name' => 'Accounts',
            'query' => "accounts.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT account_id FROM documents_accounts)",
);
```

but of course it doesn't work. I get an "Access denied" error (40).

Ideally I'd like to filter even further by querying for accounts that do not have an attached document of a given type. For example:

```
getAccountsWithout('contracts');
getAccountsWithout('quote1');
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your are not correctly authenticating with the REST API. Or that your are not correctly provide what the method call needs.

If that is not the issue. One solution is to create a customer version the service/v4_1. So that you can add your own custom call.

This can be achieved by copying the v4_1 directory giving it a name like v4_1_1.

**Rename the following:**

- SugarWebServiceImplv4_1.php to SugarWebServiceImplv4_1_1.php
- SugarWebServiceUtilv4_1.php to SugarWebServiceImplv4_1_1.php

**Change the class signatures to this:**

SugarWebServiceImplv4_1:

```
class SugarWebServiceImplv4_1_1 extends SugarWebServiceImplv4_1
```

SugarWebServiceImplv4_1:

```
class SugarWebServiceUtilv4_1_1 extends SugarWebServiceUtilv4_1
```

**Change the require/include paths in:**

- registry.php rest.php
- soap.php
- SugarWebServiceImplv4_1_1.php
- SugarWebServiceImplv4_1_1.php

so that they now point to the 4_1_1 directory.

**Implement a method in SugarWebServiceImplv4_1_1.php.**

```
function get_without_documents($session, $module_name = 'accounts', $start = 1, $offset = 20) {

        $output_list = array();

        $db = DBManagerFactory::getInstance();

        // just for example
        $sql_query = "SELECT a.id FROM accounts a WHERE a.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT account_id FROM documents_accounts)";

        $result = $db->limitQuery($sql_query, $start, $offset,false);

        while(($row = $db->fetchByAssoc($result)) != null){
          $output_list[] = $row['id'];
        }

        return array(
            'result_count'=> count($output_list),
            'next_offset' => $offset + $start,
            'entry_list' => $output_list,
        );
    }
```

**Finally register the method and it the types in registry.php and the reference the url so that it uses v4_1_1.**